# how to use a library with testcases using hardhat

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, chai

I'm using a `library` for managing `Events`. Now when I'm running the test case script then I'm getting an error.

**ERROR**

1. If I don't mention the library when I'm deploying the `Users.sol` contract.

```
AssertionError: Expected event "CreateUser" to be emitted, but it doesn't exist in the contract.
```

2. When I deploy the `Users.sol` with the library(see Testcases.js) file.

```
NomicLabsHardhatPluginError: You tried to link the contract Users with Events, which is not one of its libraries.
This contract doesn't need linking any libraries.
```

**Library: Myevents.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

library Myevents {
    
    event CreateUser(
        address indexed userAddress,
        uint256 duration
    );
}
```

**SmartContract: Users.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import {Myevents} from "./libraries/Myevents.sol";

contract Users {

  function createUser(address _user, uint256 _duration) {

      // some functionality
      emit Myevents.CreateUser(_user, _duration);

   }
}
```

**Testcase.js**

```
// deploying library
const Events = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyEvents");
const events = await Events.deploy(); 
console.log("Events library address:", events.address);

// using lib with contract
const user = await ethers.getContractFactory("Users", {
    libraries: { 
       Myevents: events.address,
}});

it("Test 1.01 Users | CreateUser ---> create user", async function () {
    await expect(
      user
    .connect(myAddress)
    .createUser(userAddress, duration)
    )
      .to.emit(events, "CreateUser")
      .withArgs(myAddress.address, duration);
  });
```

I have a couple of questions.

1. Do I have to explicitly reference the library as I did in `Testcase.js`?
2. How to use this library in testcases.js?

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not, this error explicitly tells you not to

```
NomicLabsHardhatPluginError: You tried to link the contract Users with Events, which is not one of its libraries.
This contract doesn't need linking any libraries.
```

2. Just remove the second param. When your contract gets compiled it automatically glues the lib to it. so you will have

```
const user = await ethers.getContractFactory("Users");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a contract that emits an event in an underlying library instead of the contract itself, since the contract doesn't contain the ABI of the event you probably face this error:

`AssertionError: Expected event "MyEvent" to be emitted, but it doesn't exist in the contract. Please make sure you've compiled its latest version before running the test.`

to fix it you can create a contract instance with the library ABI (The one that contains the event) and the contract address.

it's possible in two ways:

**contractInstance** `is the instance with the contract ABI`

**MyEvent** `is the event emits in the library`

**EventLibrary** `is the library that emits the event`

**EventLibraryInstance** `is the library instance that has been used in deploying the contract`

**contractInstanceWithLibraryABI** `is the instance with the library ABI and the contract address`

first:

```
let contractInstanceWithLibraryABI = await ethers.getContractAt("EventLibrary", contractInstance.address, signer)

await expect(
     await contractInstance.myFunction()
).to.emit(contractInstanceWithLibraryABI, "MyEvent")
```

second:

```
contractInstanceWithLibraryABI = await EventLibraryInstance.attach(
    contractInstance.address
)

await expect(
     await contractInstance.myFunction()
).to.emit(contractInstanceWithLibraryABI, "MyEvent")
```